# write image file larger than 4096

Tags: php, image, database

****************************EDIT***********************

i am using ODBC and found that can not read more than 4096 for a field

Any suggestions

**************************EDIT*************************

i am reading an image from db

```
$image=$row["image-contents"];
```

Now try to write the file to disk

```
$image_name="test.jpg";
$file = fopen( "images/".$image_name, "w" );
fwrite( $file, $image);
fclose( $file );
```

The problem is that the file created is only 4096 bytes and the image file is corrupt because $image is larger than 4096.

I now that fwrite use blocks for write but i dont know how do it.

Help plz!

Comment: Just to check, the size of the database column is larger than 4096 (you're using an image field or similar), right?  i.e. the file isn't truncated in the db?

Comment: @Zarigani: the fiels is large enough but i finger out that odbc driver can get more than 4096 from field and trying to find the solution

Comment: Not sure I can help but at this point, you might want to start listing things like what db you are using, what OS and how your odbc driver is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

in php.ini

```
; Handling of LONG fields.  Returns number of bytes to variables.  0 means
; passthru.
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
```

Change the 4096 value to greater and worked

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try using

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php